# M1 iMac: libdvdcss missing

Tags: imac, apple-silicon

on a new M1 iMac (macOS 12.1) I'm trying to decode a DVD using Handbrake 1.4.2.
Since libdvdcss is needed for decryption, I downloaded it from here
http://download.videolan.org/pub/libdvdcss/1.4.2/macosx/libdvdcss-1.4.2.pkg

and installed the package, just to see this error

> macgui: dlopen error: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/libdvdcss.2.dylib,
> 0x0001): tried: '/usr/local/lib/libdvdcss.2.dylib' (mach-o file, but
> is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')),
> '/usr/lib/libdvdcss.2.dylib' (no such file)

So, obviously there must be an Arm architecture-compatible version of libdvdcss, but I don't know where to get it. And I'm really stuck.

Can someone please give me the crucial tip?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get an ARM version via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh):

```
$ brew install libdvdcss
...
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/libdvdcss/manifests/1.4.3
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/libdvdcss/blobs/sha256:c96a2adbc32a57e271a9a91d338571ab9b0a6524a95e3fe48270dd5c4a277b21
==> Downloading from https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sha256:c96a2adbc32a57e271a9a91d338571ab9b0a6524a95e3fe48270dd5c4a277b21?se=2021
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring libdvdcss--1.4.3.arm64_monterey.bottle.tar.gz
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libdvdcss/1.4.3: 18 files, 404.4KB
$ file /opt/homebrew/lib/libdvdcss.*
/opt/homebrew/lib/libdvdcss.2.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64
/opt/homebrew/lib/libdvdcss.a:       current ar archive random library
/opt/homebrew/lib/libdvdcss.dylib:   Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64
```

Comment: Note that HandBrake only seems to look for the libdvdcss in `/usr/local/lib` so if you install them with Homebrew as described, you'll need to copy them to `/usr/local/lib` to get HandBrake to use them.

Comment: Von's comment tied it all together.

Comment: Note that symlinking the libdvdcss files in `/usr/local/lib` doesn't seem to work, you need to actually copy them.

Comment: I further note that the files in /usr/local/lib are themselves symlinks and won't work, so you need to Show Original in Finder  (or ls -l) to get the original file location (e.g. /usr/local/Cellar/libdvdcss/1.4.3/lib)